# inset shadow for "zigzag" border

Tags: html, footer, css, dropshadow

I'm currently designing a website, and for the footer I've created a "zigzag" border on top.
To create some depth in the website, I wanted to add a drop shadow on the triangles in the "zigzag", and this is where I'm currently stuck.

Here is an example of the footer as I have it right now: http://jsfiddle.net/CwXp4/

```css
body {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/R1yaNOy.png);
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

#footer:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  height: 21px;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #333 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0, linear-gradient(-45deg, #333 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Is there someone out there with some tips for me on how to add a drop shadow?

Comment: Did you search for 'drop-shadow' ?

Comment: I've been searching this website (and others) for the result I want, but I can't seem to find anything that's working for me.

Im quite new to webdesign and css.

What I tried was normal box-shadow, but that just got put under the triangles, like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ynxu3/

Comment: Here's an images of what I want to achieve http://www.webdesignshock.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Footer107.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can somehow make the shadow with the same gradients that you are using to make the zigzag.

CSS

```css
#footer:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -21px;
    height: 22px;
    background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #333 50%, blue 50%, transparent 55%) 0 0,
                linear-gradient(-45deg, #333 50%, blue 50%, transparent 55%) 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 40px 47px, 40px 47px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/R1yaNOy.png);
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

#footer:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  height: 22px;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #333 50%, blue 50%, transparent 55%) 0 0, linear-gradient(-45deg, #333 50%, blue 50%, transparent 55%) 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 40px 47px, 40px 47px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer"></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwXp4/4/)

You could also get the shadow with a webkit-filter shadow, but this has limited support

CSS

```css
#footer:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -21px;
    height: 22px;
    background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #333 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0,
                linear-gradient(-45deg, #333 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;

    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 40px 47px, 40px 47px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(red 0px -5px 5px);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/R1yaNOy.png);
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}

#footer:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  height: 22px;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, #333 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0, linear-gradient(-45deg, #333 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 40px 47px, 40px 47px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(red 0px -5px 5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="footer"></div>
```

[fiddle with filter](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/CwXp4/6/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was more or less what I was looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/CwXp4/5/. How would you do it with this webkit-filter, just to compare the two options?

Comment: Added example using a filter. Doesn't work too well, I don't know exactly why. It will work only in webkit.