# ZigZag bottom border for div with box-shadow

Tags: css

How can I make border-bottom "zigzag" but with box-shadow as on the screenshot below?

[div with zigzag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQjpY.png)

As you can see on the screenshot - the main background is white and div's background is also white. I tried this way(which doesn't work like I need):

```
after {
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4) 15px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4) 15px, transparent 0);
        background-position: left-bottom;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-size: 35px 35px;
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 32px; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21515886/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif How does my question duplicate that one?

Comment: did you read it and check the different code there?

Comment: I did and not find an answer for my case. If you watch the screenshot you'd see that there is a white background and the `box-shadow` of `div` used not for border itself. Those are main issues - white back for both main page and my block and box-shadow.

Comment: If you want the `box-shadow` to pop out from underneath (basically, have the zig-zag actually affect the shape of the `div`), it's possible that they're using a CSS clip-path alongside `filter: drop-shadow()` instead of an actual `box-shadow`. Clip-path support [can be pretty hit-or-miss](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), though. This is just a hunch, I could be very wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to do, you need to use the concept of SVG for the background image,

refer : [Container with zigzag border at bottom only apply to the border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650302/container-with-zigzag-border-at-bottom-only-apply-to-the-border)

```css
div {
      width: 50%;
      height: 280px;
      border: 1px #ededed solid;
      border-bottom: 0;
      background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg viewBox="0 0 200 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M -15 110 L100 10 L215 110" fill="none" stroke="%23ededed" stroke-width="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></svg>');
      background-position: bottom left;
/*     box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; */
      background-size: 10% auto;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't give the desired result.